# Adding parameters to Array Product function in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

So I've been scratching my head trying to find a solution to this.

I need a method that will take any number of arrays that I need to collect the [product](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/product) of.

1 array:

```
return [A, B, C] # => [A, B, C]
```

2 arrays:

```
return [A, B, C].product([1, 2, 3]) # => [[A, 1], [A, 2], [A, 3], [B, 1] ... [C, 3]]
```

3 arrays:

```
return [A, B, C].product([1, 2, 3,],[x, y, z]) # => [[A, 1, x], [A, 1, y], ... [C, 3, z]]
```

So my current solution is this case switch, which is functional but inconvenient.

```
case options.count
when 1
  options[0].values
when 2
  options[0].values.product(options[1].values)
when 3
  options[0].values.product(options[1].values,
                            options[2].values)
when 4
  options[0].values.product(options[1].values,
                            options[2].values,
                            options[3].values)
end
```

What I'm looking for is a method that procedurally or recursively returns the product of an unknown number of arrays. The output needs to be like the above arrays.

I've tried:

```
array = options[0].values
options.each_with_index do |option, i|
  array = array.product(option.values) if i > 0
end
return array
```

But it returns:

```
[[[A, 1], x], [[A, 1], y], [[A, 1], z], [[A, 2], x], ... [[C, 3], z]]
```

Which groups the values incorrectly.

Comment: I'm a little confused about this question. Aren't you describing the built in `product` method? How is what you're looking for different? Maybe I'm misunderstanding. If what you're looking for is `[1,2].product([3,4], [5,6]) # => [[1,3,5],[1,3,6],[1,4,5],[1,4,6], ...]` that's exactly what `product` does

Comment: I have a variable number of arrays to put through the `product` method and didn't know the `*` prefix to an array separates it out as different arguments instead of the array becoming just the first argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this helps

```
a =  [["a", "b", "c"], ["d", "e", "f"], ["g", "h", "i"]]
a[0].product(*a[1..a.length])
#=> [["a", "d", "g"], ["a", "d", "h"], ["a", "d", "i"], ["a", "e", "g"], ["a", "e", "h"], ["a", "e", "i"], ["a", "f", "g"], ["a", "f", "h"], ["a", "f", "i"], ["b", "d", "g"], ["b", "d", "h"], ["b", "d", "i"], ["b", "e", "g"], ["b", "e", "h"], ["b", "e", "i"], ["b", "f", "g"], ["b", "f", "h"], ["b", "f", "i"], ["c", "d", "g"], ["c", "d", "h"], ["c", "d", "i"], ["c", "e", "g"], ["c", "e", "h"], ["c", "e", "i"], ["c", "f", "g"], ["c", "f", "h"], ["c", "f", "i"]]
# or 
a.slice!(0).product(*a) #Note: this mutates array.
# or
a[0].product(*a.drop(1)) # suggested by Cary Swoveland
```

Comment: Consider using `a.first` instead of `a[0]`:)

Comment: @engineersmnky : didn't get the last part - where it wouldn't have the impact? `a.shift` will change it for `*a` later, I think; like `a.slice!(0)` does. No?

Comment: @kiddorails my apologies should be `def multi_product(*a); a.shift.product(*a); end` then called as `multi_product(*a)` since splat will create a new `Array` the original `a` would not be modified. Furthermore you could go with `def multi_product(a); first,*rest = a; first.product(*rest);end`

Comment: You could use `*a.drop(1)` as the argument.

Comment: I'm accepting this as the answer since it made more since in my particular situation to see it spelled out in those suggestions.

Answer (score 5):

How about something like:

```
def multi_product(base, *args)
  base.product(*args)
end
```

results:

```
multi_product(['A', 'B', 'C'])
# => [["A"], ["B"], ["C"]]
multi_product(['A', 'B', 'C'], [1, 2, 3])
# => [["A", 1], ["A", 2], ["A", 3], ["B", 1], ["B", 2], ["B", 3], ["C", 1], ["C", 2], ["C", 3]]
multi_product(['A', 'B', 'C'], [1, 2, 3], ['x', 'y', 'z'])
# => [["A", 1, "x"], ["A", 1, "y"], ["A", 1, "z"], ["A", 2, "x"], ["A", 2, "y"], ["A", 2, "z"], ["A", 3, "x"], ["A", 3, "y"], ["A", 3, "z"], ["B", 1, "x"], ["B", 1, "y"], ["B", 1, "z"], ["B", 2, "x"], ["B", 2, "y"], ["B", 2, "z"], ["B", 3, "x"], ["B", 3, "y"], ["B", 3, "z"], ["C", 1, "x"], ["C", 1, "y"], ["C", 1, "z"], ["C", 2, "x"], ["C", 2, "y"], ["C", 2, "z"], ["C", 3, "x"], ["C", 3, "y"], ["C", 3, "z"]]
multi_product(['A', 'B', 'C'], [1, 2, 3], ['x', 'y', 'z'], [4, 5, 6])
# => [["A", 1, "x", 4], ["A", 1, "x", 5], ["A", 1, "x", 6], ["A", 1, "y", 4], ["A", 1, "y", 5], ["A", 1, "y", 6], ["A", 1, "z", 4], ["A", 1, "z", 5], ["A", 1, "z", 6], ["A", 2, "x", 4], ["A", 2, "x", 5], ["A", 2, "x", 6], ["A", 2, "y", 4], ["A", 2, "y", 5], ["A", 2, "y", 6], ["A", 2, "z", 4], ["A", 2, "z", 5], ["A", 2, "z", 6], ["A", 3, "x", 4], ["A", 3, "x", 5], ["A", 3, "x", 6], ["A", 3, "y", 4], ["A", 3, "y", 5], ["A", 3, "y", 6], ["A", 3, "z", 4], ["A", 3, "z", 5], ["A", 3, "z", 6], ["B", 1, "x", 4], ["B", 1, "x", 5], ["B", 1, "x", 6], ["B", 1, "y", 4], ["B", 1, "y", 5], ["B", 1, "y", 6], ["B", 1, "z", 4], ["B", 1, "z", 5], ["B", 1, "z", 6], ["B", 2, "x", 4], ["B", 2, "x", 5], ["B", 2, "x", 6], ["B", 2, "y", 4], ["B", 2, "y", 5], ["B", 2, "y", 6], ["B", 2, "z", 4], ["B", 2, "z", 5], ["B", 2, "z", 6], ["B", 3, "x", 4], ["B", 3, "x", 5], ["B", 3, "x", 6], ["B", 3, "y", 4], ["B", 3, "y", 5], ["B", 3, "y", 6], ["B", 3, "z", 4], ["B", 3, "z", 5], ["B", 3, "z", 6], ["C", 1, "x", 4], ["C", 1, "x", 5], ["C", 1, "x", 6], ["C", 1, "y", 4], ["C", 1, "y", 5], ["C", 1, "y", 6], ["C", 1, "z", 4], ["C", 1, "z", 5], ["C", 1, "z", 6], ["C", 2, "x", 4], ["C", 2, "x", 5], ["C", 2, "x", 6], ["C", 2, "y", 4], ["C", 2, "y", 5], ["C", 2, "y", 6], ["C", 2, "z", 4], ["C", 2, "z", 5], ["C", 2, "z", 6], ["C", 3, "x", 4], ["C", 3, "x", 5], ["C", 3, "x", 6], ["C", 3, "y", 4], ["C", 3, "y", 5], ["C", 3, "y", 6], ["C", 3, "z", 4], ["C", 3, "z", 5], ["C", 3, "z", 6]]
```

What it does is take one required parameter (*base*) which responds to `product` and then the `*args` takes a variable number of other parameters and stores them in an array *args*. You can then use `*` to deconstruct an array back into an argument list, which is done inside the call to `product(*args)` so that (in the case of the second example) ends up looking like

```
['A', 'B', 'C'].product([1, 2, 3], ['x', 'y', 'z'])
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The piece of information I was missing was that putting `*` in front of an array separated it out to multiple method parameters.